# Can't change position when code works with background-color

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I want to affect the `position` of any item on my page when it is clicked. How can i do this without using id names? I have a working piece of code which works when changing `background-color` but doesn't seem to want to work when i change it to `position`.

```
$(document).click(function(event) {
    $(event.target).css({'background-color': 'blue'});
});
```

Any help always appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to delegate the event in order to target more precisely the element, but want You are trying to achieve could cause really bad performance issues.

Try this:

```
$(document).on('click', '*', function(event) {
    $(this).css({'position': 'relative'});
});
```

Comment: Thanks a lot that's got it working. What kind of performance issues do you mean?

Comment: You are binding a click event to EVERY element in your page, imagine a really complex DOM with lots and lots of elements jquery would have to traverse the whole document and for each element it finds, bind the click handler to it.

Comment: Ah okay. I'm planning on putting this into a Chrome extension which won't have the script running all the time. Only when the user requests it.